# "Installing extension pack ..." stuck at 0%

Tags: virtualbox, 15.10

On a freshly installed Ubuntu 15.10 I installed VirtualBox (from Ubuntu's repository), created two VMs and imported an OVA, at which point I was told to install the extension pack.

So I downloaded the extension pack for my version of VirtualBox, and executed it, which made VirtualBox open this dialog:

[image: Extensions: Installing extension pack progress bar 0%]

Problem: After an hour it is still stuck at 0%.
Question: How can I fix it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Installing the Extension Pack from the command line will often solve this issue (as you have already demonstrated). The most comprehensive command line would be:

```
sudo VBoxManage extpack install --replace <tarball>
```

where `<tarball>` needs to be replaced with the actual path and filename of the downloaded Extension Pack. The use of the `--replace` option means that any older version of the same Extension Pack will be first uninstalled. Without the `--replace` option in place the command line *could* fail.

It would be wise as well to clean up any remaining temporary files and directories after the installation by running the following command:

```
sudo VBoxManage extpack cleanup
```

and perhaps for the sake of completion check the installation of the Extension Pack by running the following command as well:

```
sudo VBoxManage list extpacks
```

The reference below gives full details of these and other  command line options for `VBoxManage`.

**Reference:**

- [8.36. VBoxManage extpack](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-extpack)

Comment: So is the actual problem that VirtualBox isn't trying to do it as root (and also not handling lack of permissions gracefully)?

Comment: This is my suspicion and certainly using `sudo` with the commandline `VBoxManage` usually solves the issue. My own practice has been to use the command line exclusively rather than the gui, mostly because there are so many more options available!

Answer (score 5):

I fixed the problem by installing the extension **as root** from command-line:

```
$ sudo VBoxManage extpack install ~/Downloads/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-5.0.12-104815.vbox-extpack 
Swipe your finger across the fingerprint reader
0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%
Successfully installed "Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack".
```

A solution not involving root would be better, but at least this worked.

Comment: `Swipe your finger across the fingerprint reader` ? Is this for real? what if I dont have fingerprint reader? how it knows your computer has one? why it is necessary?

Comment: @edwardtorvalds: If you don't have a fingerprint reader, something like `Type your password` will appear instead.

Answer (score 4):

This may have occurred, because the licence agreement had not been accepted.

Install the extension pack from within the VirtualBox application.

Open Preferences and select the Extensions tab.

Click on the down arrow on the right side.

[image]

Select the downloaded extension pack and click on Install.

[image]

The licence agreement appears.

[image]

Scroll down and click on I Agree.

[image]

Enter your password ... now the extension pack is installed successfully.

[image]

[image]

**Update addressing your response that you still cannot add the extension pack**

Install and use the VirtualBox version 5.0 from the ORACLE VirtualBox repository.

Completely uninstall VirtualBox :

```
sudo apt-get purge "^virtualbox-.*"  
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Download and register the ORACLE public key :

```
wget -q -O - https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox.asc | sudo apt-key add -
```

Add the ORACLE VirtualBox repository to the software sources :

```
echo "deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian wily contrib" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oracle-vbox.list
```

Update the repositories :

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install VirtualBox 5.0 :

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-5.0
```

Now add the extension pack as described before.

**Note for other users reading this answer, in case they use another Ubuntu edition as 15.10 :**

You have to replace `wily` with the Ubuntu edition you are using when adding the repository !

As of Ubuntu 16.04 the ORACLE public key to download and register has  changed :

`oracle_vbox.asc` has to be replaced with `oracle_vbox_2016.asc` !

Comment: Unfortunately it is exactly the same problem: "Installing extension pack" stucked at 0% :-/ Thanks for the idea though!

Comment: oops check my new answer before wasting time

Comment: Since I already fixed the problem I can't test this one... I will accept the answer that worked for me (mine) but give you the bounty for the effort, thanks! :-)

Comment: @NicolasRaoul : You cannot install the ext-pack via GUI, so there must be something wrong with the vbox installation ... sure, this is not a "big thing", as the ext-pack can be installed via terminal. That is the reason why I updated the answer with an alternative way, which also gives you the opportunity to always use the latest version of vbox. Generally I test everything before posting something. I have tested this solution on all currently supported Ubuntu versions and everything including the ext-pack installation works properly. :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, got stuck at 0% no matter which version I tried. Installing Virtualbox and Extension Pack via terminal finally worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-ext-pack
```

Answer (score 0):

i ran into this issue but the solution was rather simple. Just downgrade the Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack (instead of 5.1.12-112440 used just 5.0.0).
Good luck yall.