# Ubuntu breaking after initial restart

Tags: system-installation, virtualbox

When I installed Ubuntu on virtualbox (I'm on windows 10) everything went fine the installation was no problem but when I do the initial restart this happens:

[image]

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press <kbd>right ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd> to switch to TTY, then switch back with <kbd>right ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f7</kbd>. Then log in and install the VirtualBox Guest Additions.

Please see this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/719378/522934) on how to install the extensions pack, beside that you have to download it by hand from the oracle website the installation process from within the VirtualBox GUI is the same.

Comment: After pressing control+f1 and control+f7 a couple times it fixed itself thanks!

Comment: The problem itself may persist unless you install the guest additions tho.

Comment: What is the guest addition?

Comment: This is an `.iso` file you can load into your VM to install for example graphic resizing, copy&pasting and drag&drop.

Comment: Can you find this on the virtual box website itself or somewhere else?

Comment: You can find the guest extension pack as download here https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads as well as the `.iso` disk file. If you're using VirtualBox 5.0.20 you should use the extensions approach to get this file available.

Comment: Alright will do when I have time thanks a lot man